# How to Get Distinct More than one Column Rows in one Column

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, unpivot

I want 5 column's Rows in one Column And Unique Rows in That Column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT date,accept_date, question_date,success_date
FROM user_presentation;
```

I Got Rows as:

```
date       accept_date question_date success_date
2018-12-07 2018-11-23  2018-12-21    2019-01-04
2018-12-21 2018-12-07  2019-01-04    2019-01-18
2019-01-04 2018-12-21  2019-01-18    2019-02-01
2019-01-18 2019-01-04  2019-02-01    2019-02-15
2019-02-01 2019-01-18  2019-02-15    2019-03-01
```

I want All Rows in one column But Only Unique Values

Comment: Read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide example data and expected results in a ascii data table format (no images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT val
  FROM 
     ( SELECT 'date' date_type 
            , date val
         FROM user_presentation
        UNION 
       SELECT 'accept_date' 
            , accept_date 
         FROM user_presentation
        UNION 
       SELECT 'question_date'
            , question_date  
         FROM user_presentation
        UNION 
       SELECT 'success_date'
            , success_date
         FROM user_presentation
     ) normalized;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you want, and an example would make it clear. If @Strawberry is on the right track, then it can be greatly simplified as UNION will always remove duplicates.

Simplified version is:

```
SELECT date val FROM user_presentation
UNION 
SELECT accept_date FROM user_presentation
UNION 
SELECT question_date FROM user_presentation
UNION 
SELECT success_date FROM user_presentation
```

Comment: Yep, but there's a very specific reason why I wrote it that way- the clue is in the alias I assigned to the subquery.

Comment: Must be a friday @Strawberry because I can't for the life of me see why or how the subquery is "normalised". Could you explain? Is it perhaps a mySql thing as I'm not an expert on that one and I know it has some quirks.